# SQL Server database performance using Prometheus

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, grafana, prometheus

I am new to Prometheus, I want to use the results of a SQL Server stored procedure in Prometheus Grafana with using Web API (not using Docker or agent) to see the performances of my SQL Server database, I have cloned the GitHub project called Prometheous.net in Visual Studio, but my question is how can I use it with my SQL Server database to collect metrics?

Comment: Procedural code (like stored procedures) is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: My stored procedure is based on MSSQL (SQL-server)

Comment: @HUMANAZ although this is an Influx example, there is a dashboard and scripts here (https://grafana.com/dashboards/5040) that I created to gather Windows counters and store them for MSSQL Server monitoring. If you change the `Invoke-WebRequest` and the parameters it passes, I think this will create what you need. Then you can either tweak the names, or use the supplied dashboard